# What's wrong with this program? Word separation program

Tags: c

I'm kind of new to this, so I'm stuck on something that's probably very simple.

In this program I'm trying to separate each word from an array into a two dimensional array, as well as any periods, commas, or semicolons. However, it only reprints the sentence in one line. I've done a couple tests and it seems that the first for loop never recognizes a space, commas, periods, or semicolons. Can someone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char wordProblem[1024];
char wordProblemWords[200][20];

printf("Please enter a word problem.\n");

fgets ( wordProblem, 1024, stdin );
int length = strlen (wordProblem);
int i;
int wordNumber = 0;
int letterOfWord = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if (wordProblem[i]==" ") {
        ++wordNumber;
        letterOfWord = 0;
    }else if (wordProblem[i]=="." || wordProblem[i]=="," || wordProblem[i]==";"){
        ++wordNumber;
        letterOfWord = 0;
        wordProblemWords[wordNumber][letterOfWord] = wordProblem[i];
        wordNumber;
        letterOfWord = 0;
    }else{
        wordProblemWords[wordNumber][letterOfWord] = wordProblem[i];
        ++letterOfWord;
    }
}

int j;
for (j = 0; j <= wordNumber; j++){

    printf("%s", wordProblemWords[j]);
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I've changed the program a bit and the problem was solved. If you want to correct any other problems (I'm sure there are tons) here's the new code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>//based on what user3629249 said

int main()
{
char wordProblem[1024];
char wordProblemWords[200][20];

printf("Please enter a word problem.\n");

fgets ( wordProblem, 1024, stdin );
int length = strlen (wordProblem);
int i;
int wordNumber = 0;
int letterOfWord = 0;
for ( i = 0; i <= length; i++){
    if (wordProblem[i]==' ') {          //single quotes instead of double (tivn)
        wordProblemWords[wordNumber][letterOfWord] = '\0';//added this to have a null at the end of the string, removes gibberish
        ++wordNumber;
        letterOfWord = 0;
    }else if (wordProblem[i]=='.' || wordProblem[i]==',' || wordProblem[i]==';'){
        ++wordNumber;
        letterOfWord = 0;
        wordProblemWords[wordNumber][letterOfWord] = wordProblem[i];
        wordProblemWords[wordNumber][letterOfWord] = '\0'//again to remove gibberish
    }else{
        wordProblemWords[wordNumber][letterOfWord] = wordProblem[i];
        ++letterOfWord;
    }
}

int j;
for (j = 0; j <= wordNumber; j++){

    printf("%s", wordProblemWords[j]);
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: the code needs to allow for multiple spaces, etc, so each space, in a string of spaces, after the first space does not count another word

Comment: this line: '        wordNumber;' raises a compiler warning.  Please enable all warnings, re-compile the code, fix the warnings, then re-post the code

Comment: the code, as posted, results in an implicit declaration of strlen().  this needs to be corrected by adding the statement: '#include <string.h>'

Comment: I've updated the code based on what the answer by tivn and made a couple changes to remove excess gibberish that was in the console log. I've also included the statement in your third comment. When I build it now, no warnings showed up so I suppose your 2nd comment is cleared. So, how would I allow for multiple spaces? I don't really need to, since I'm making a larger program based on this and am banking on the fact that the input has correct grammar, but if there is a short edit I could make then I'll include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use single quote for comparing single char. Double quote means string.

```
if (wordProblem[i]==' ') {
    ++wordNumber;
    letterOfWord = 0;
} else if (wordProblem[i]=='.' || wordProblem[i]==',' || wordProblem[i]==';'){
    ...
```

Also please note that `fgets` will include newline in the result.

Comment: Thanks man! Really appreciate it, can't believe how quickly someone replies. ^^